# Why am I getting this error? (object.__init__() takes no parameters)

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, legs):
        self.name = name
        self.legs = legs

class Bear:
    def __init__(self, name, legs, hibernate = 'yes'):
        super().__init__(name, legs)
        self.hibernate = hibernate
        
        
obj = Bear('Yogi', 4)
print(obj.name)
print(obj.legs)
print(obj.hibernate)
```

when I run the code I get the error:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Why is using the super() function not working here?

Comment: ```class Bear(Animal):```

Comment: Cheers, the python docs are - as almost always - really good. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Use inheritance:

```py
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, legs):
        self.name = name
        self.legs = legs

class Bear(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, legs, hibernate = 'yes'):
        super().__init__(name, legs)
        self.hibernate = hibernate
        
        
obj = Bear('Yogi', 4)
print(obj.name)
print(obj.legs)
print(obj.hibernate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, legs):
        self.name = name
        self.legs = legs

class Bear(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, legs, hibernate = 'yes'):
        super().__init__(name, legs)
        self.hibernate = hibernate
        
        
obj = Bear('Yogi', 4)
print(obj.name)
print(obj.legs)
print(obj.hibernate)
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to inherit the Bear class from Animal

Class Bear(Animal):

Try this and then run your code